# For what positive reals $a^2+b^2+1>(a+1)(b+1)$?

Tags: inequality

> For what positive reals $a^2+b^2+1>(a+1)(b+1)$?

A question I've come up with. AM-GM doesn't seem to give anything directly.

P.S. I've edited the question to what it originally was (Jack has answered it). Otherwise it's simple.

Comment: Do you mean, what are the solutions of the inequality for which $a, b > 0$?

Comment: @Travis right. I want to find intervals $A,B$ that are subsets of positive reals and for which $a\in A, b\in B$ implies the inequality

Comment: The solution set looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfnjD.png (the yellow region). I don't think there is a simpler relationship.

Comment: @user236182 As kennytm's picture suggests, the solution set to the inequality (well, inequalities) is not a product of intervals, i.e., a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes. Do you really mean you want such a product of intervals (i.e., a rectangle inside the full solution set), or do you want the full solution set (the yellow region in the picture) itself?

Comment: @kennytm Ellipse?

Comment: @zed111 Yes it is an ellipse, as the inequality can be rewritten as the quadratic curve $a^2-ab+b^2 -a-b>0$.

Comment: To take some graphical notions into consideration, it worth noticing that $f(x, y)=x^{2}-xy+y^{2}-x-y$ is a paraboloid in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and it attains its minimal value at $(1, 1)$ and it's equal to $-1$. (some multivariable calculus is needed).Moreover it intersects with $z=0$ plane by an ellipse (its equation is $x^{2}-xy+y^{2}-x-y=0$). Now try evaluating the ellipse vertices' coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^2+b^2+1-(a+1)(b+1) = a^2+b^2-ab-a-b = 0$$
is the equation of an ellipse with centre in $(a,b)=(1,1)$ and vertices in $$(0,0),(2,2),\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right),\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right),$$ hence the inequality holds for every $(a,b)$ outside that ellipse:

$\hspace1in$[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that the inequality is equivalent to $a^2+b^2 \geq ab+a+b$.

Now, by AM-GM: $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$.

Now assume $b \geq a$. Then $ab \geq 3b > 2b \geq a+b$, so that gets the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2+b^2+1-(a+1)(b+1)=\dfrac 1 2 \cdot \{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(a-b)^2\} \ge 0$

equality holds if and only if $a=b=1$

Comment: $$a^2+b^2+1-(a+1)(b+1)=\frac{1}{2}\left((a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(a-b)^2\right)-1\ge -1$$